# Calculate cells value related to value in two other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns in my excel sheet,
"Qnty In pack" , "packs Qnty"  , "Total Qnty"

I want write a Macro that when ever the user populate any 2 cells out of the 3  in the spread sheet the missing value will be calculated and placed in the right cell.
if cells "Qnty In pack" and "packs Qnty" are populated  by the user the cell "Total Qnty" will be calculated and populated,
if cells "Total Qnty" and "packs Qnty" are populated  by the use cell  "Qnty In pack" will be calculated and populated and so on.

Comment: Seems like a fun little exercise, but as mentioned, you can't expect us to do the work for you. See [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the follwing could work. But note that it can easily come to an issue when you try to correct a value where all 3 have been already set. Then VBA cannot know which one to calculate.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim QntyRange As Range
    Set QntyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:D")
    
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, QntyRange)
    
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim eRow As Variant
        For Each eRow In AffectedRange.Rows
            With QntyRange
                If .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value = 0 Then
                    .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value = .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value * .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value
                ElseIf .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value = 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value <> 0 Then
                    .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value = .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value / .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value
                ElseIf .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value = 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value <> 0 Then
                    .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value = .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value / .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value
                ElseIf .Cells(eRow.Row, 1).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 2).Value <> 0 And .Cells(eRow.Row, 3).Value <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox "All 3 columns contain numbers. Unable to calculate."
                    Application.Undo 'undo change because otherwise quantities are wrong!
                End If
            End With
        Next eRow
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this simple formula (in cell C2):

```
=A2*B2
```

In cell A2 you put something like:

```
=IF(B2<>0, C2/B2,"")
```

In cell B2 you put something like:

```
=IF(A2<>0, C2/A2, "")
```

If ever you then overwrite those formulas with values, then those values will be used as input for the formula(s) in the other column(s).

Comment: This would only calculate C, but he want's if some one enters A and C then B is calculated and if someone enters B and C then A is calculated …

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: you're right, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: well but then you run into circle dependencies if you write all 3 formluas at the same time to overwrite 2 of them by constant values later.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: that's not a problem, there's an option in Excel to allow circular references.